# Multiple roots in equation in $e^x = x^{nx}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots, radicals, lambert-w

When I was observing the increment trend difference between exponential functions and power functions, I decided to try solving the roots of the two equations. The most apparent way is by Lambert W function, which I do something as follows:

$e^x = x^4$

$(1/x) \ln(1/x) = -1/4$

$x = e^{-W(-1/4)}$

Evaluating the answer in Wolfram Alpha, I got $1.4296$ something, which is one of the three roots observed in the graph $e^x = x^4$.
How do I proceed from this point? Do I try to expand it into a Taylor series and see how it goes?
That would be tedious, but is that the right way?

Comment: Looking from WolframAlpha's answers, as $x$ may be negative, sometimes adding absolute signs may be necessary when taking roots or log. E.g. From $e^x=x^4$, then $e^{x/4} = \lvert x\rvert$ and $x = 4\ln\lvert x\rvert$.

Comment: Unlike $e^x = x^4$, the equation $e^x = x^{nx}$ in the title is much easier to solve and does not require $W$.

Comment: The equation in the title doesn't match the equation in the body of the question.

Comment: Sorry everyone, the question wasn't well structured. Yes the goal is to find all solution of $e^x = x^n$ and $x^xn$ is a typo. 人(◞‸◟)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)

$$e^x=x^{nx}\ \ \ (n\in\mathbb{N}_+)$$
$$e^x=e^{nx\ln(x)}$$
$$x=e^\frac{1}{n}$$

Now I assume you are interested only in the solutions in the reals.

2.)

$$e^x=x^4$$

See the graph of the function $x\mapsto e^x-x^4$ in the reals. There are not too much extremas. Therefore you could solve the equation numerically.

There are at least two ways of solving in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

a)

$$e^x=x^4$$
$$x=4\ln(|x|)$$
$$\frac{1}{x}\ln(|x|)=\color{red}+\frac{1}{4}$$
$$x=-4W_0\left(\pm\frac{1}{4}\right),-4W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)$$
$\ $

$$e^{-W_{0/1}\left(\pm\frac{1}{4}\right)}=-4W_{0/-1}\left(\pm\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

b)

$$e^x=x^4$$
$$e^{\frac{1}{4}x}=|x|$$
$$1=|x|e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}$$
$$|x|e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}=1$$
$$-\frac{1}{4}|x|e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}=-\frac{1}{4}$$
$$x=-4W_0\left(\pm\frac{1}{4}\right),-4W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

We can represent a closed-form function (like Lambert W or the natural exponential function) by its series representations, its differential or integral equations and its algebraic transformation rules.

If you want numeric values for your closed-form solutions, you have to use the series representations of Lambert W.